# Increasing a timer everytime an evaluation is false

Tags: c#, timer

I'm measuring the amount of time certain actions in Internet Explorer take.  One of the actions I'm measuring is launching another application via a link in IE.  To measure how long this application takes to launch I start a timer after the link has been clicked in IE and I had planned on stopping it once the application had fully loaded.  The problem there was that my application would go to execute the next line since the evaluation would always be false as there wasn't enough time between lines for the external app to load.

```
try
{
    Process[] externApp = Process.GetProcessesByName("External");
    System.Timers.Timer runningWindow = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    runningWindow.Start();
    while (runningWindow.Enabled)
    {
        if (externApp[0].Responding)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            output[2] = timer.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
            runningWindow.Stop();
        }
        runningWindow.Interval += 100;
    }
    externApp[0].Kill();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Above is how I'm currently trying to get my application to hang while I wait for the other application to respond.

Since I wasn't sure how to wait for another application to load I decided to use a timer to postpone the execution of the next line after I check if the other application is running.  If the application wasn't running I would increase the timer by a tenth of a second then check again.  However the problem I was running into here is that I don't think I'm increasing the timer as my time measurement is always 0 for this step.

So how do I increase my timer if my external application isn't responding?

Comment: I think this is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Don't use a Timer but the StopWatch class.

Comment: @Steve how would the stop watch make my application pause while the external app loads?  I thought it was only for measuring time.

Comment: Process.WaitForInputIdle with a long enough timeout, then measure the stopwatch.

Comment: `WaitForInputIdle` is, unfortunately, a crude tool. The application could still be loading and completely unresponsive, but because at an early part of its startup it created a window of any type and managed to go input idle on that window, `WaitForInputIdle` will return (because it's effectively a process-wide flag that only gets transitioned in one direction)

Comment: @Steve the program still executed too quickly.  The external app process didn't yet exist for it to `.WaitForInputIdle()`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what alternatives have we?

Comment: Uhm probably knowing the Window Title of the Main Window is a possible alternative

Comment: @Steve how is that different than tracking the process?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do when your app is loaded and responding to user input?

Comment: @Steve when the external app has loaded I want to stop the Stopwatch that is currently running and record the time.

Comment: Albeit unreliable for all cases I would try to use WaitForInputIdle. It is strange your comment before about the external app process not existant when you call WaitForInputIdle. If you have retrieved with GetProcessesByName then you have the process and you could use WaitForInputIdle. If it is your code that is faster than the Process.Start then you could add a Thread.Sleep of some seconds before trying to read the processes. Can you add the code that starts the "External" app?

Comment: @Steve well the program currently executes so quickly that it can't even grab `GetProcessesByName()` for my external app before the app I'm making as moved onto the next line (as that process doesn't exist yet)

Comment: The insert the GetProcessByName inside a loop with a Thread.Sleep(100) to wait for the external process to be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albeit unreliable for the reasons explained above in comments you can still use the Process.WaitForInputIdle to get an approximate evaluation of the startup time required by your app

```
// Launch the external app...
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"D:\temp\MyExternalApp.exe";
psi.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\temp";

// Init measure
Stopwatch sw = StopWatch.StartNew();
Process.Start(psi);
Process[] externApp = null;
int cnt = 0;
bool ready = false;
while (externApp == null || externApp.Length == 0 || cnt == 600)
{
    // Loop until the process appears in the process list.
    // This is taxing for the performances. Heisenberg here
    externApp = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyExternalApp");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    cnt++;
}
if(cnt >= 600) 
    MessageBox.Show("Something has gone terribly wrong launching the external app");
else
    ready = externApp[0].WaitForInputIdle(30000);

sw.Stop();

if(!ready)
    MessageBox.Show("Not ready after:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms"); 
else
    MessageBox.Show("Ready after:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
```

Another approch could be used (still with WaitForInputIdle) if you cannot start a Stopwatch the exact instant in which your external process has been started (like it seems with your comment about starting the ExternalApp through a browseer) In this case we could try to get the start time using the same named property in the Process class

```
Process[] externApp = null;
int cnt = 0;
bool ready = false;
while (externApp == null || externApp.Length == 0 || cnt == 600)
{
    // Again we are waiting to see the process in the list of processes
    externApp = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyExternalApp");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    cnt++;
}
if(cnt >= 600) 
    MessageBox.Show("Something has gone terribly wrong launching the external app");
else
{
    ready = externApp[0].WaitForInputIdle(30000);
    DateTime readyAt = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan ts = readyAt - externApp[0].StartTime;
    MessageBox.Show("Ready after:" + ts.TotalMilliseconds + " ms"); 
}
```

Comment: I feel like this is on the right track but the problem is you're manually starting the application.  I'm specifically trying to time it from launching through the browser.  So I can run through this and it'll still give me a time before the external app has actually launched (because I'm still doing it through the browser).

Comment: Unsure to understand how do you do it through the browser. However the Process class has a property named StartTime and you can calculate the difference against the current time using the same technique used with the direct execution of the external app. Just with the TimeSpan class.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the Current time before starting IE:

```
 DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
```

And in the end subtract it from the finish time like:

```
double SecondsElapsed = (DateTime.Now-start).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: But that still doesn't tell me when the external app launched and loaded to have a time to subtract the current `DateTime.Now` from

Comment: Then as rory.ap said, Your problem is not calculating the elapsed time but knowing when the external application is loaded and thats a totally different question

Comment: Well sure determining when the external application has loaded would be a better alternative but since I couldn't figure out how to do that I went with this method.  Because that's how I'm doing it I wouldn't say my question has changed.